# NameError: missing class name (`org.bouncycastle.jce.provider.BouncyCastleProvider')

Tags: jruby, bouncycastle, jce

Using JRuby 9.0.5.0 I'm trying to connect IBM Websphere MQ with SSL.
I've downloaded the bouncy cast provider jar file (bcprov-jdk15on-154.jar) and placed it on this location: /opt/mqm/java/jre64/jre/lib

In the code I've required that jar file and then imported the class:

```
require "java"
require "/opt/mqm/java/lib/com.ibm.mqjms.jar"
require "/opt/mqm/java/jre64/jre/lib/bcprov-jdk15on-154.jar"

java_import org.bouncycastle.jce.provider.BouncyCastleProvider
```

Running the script returns

```
NameError: missing class name (`org.bouncycastle.jce.provider.BouncyCastleProvider')
```

Where should I place the file to import the class?

Comment: if `/opt/mqm/java/jre64/jre/lib` is part of the JVM's class-path than you should not need to require the .jar. also normally, it should have just worked when you load jruby-openssl - but of course there's little testing under IBM's JVM and it also might be specific to your app (e.g. if you're using WebSphere).

Answer (score -1):

To fix the issue I have installed the bouncy-castle-java gem

```
gem 'bouncy-castle-java'
```

And then required it in the script

```
require "bouncy-castle-java"
```

The following statement works fine now

```
java_import org.bouncycastle.jce.provider.BouncyCastleProvider
```

Comment: BC gem is discouraged and outdated (as bc .jar are now been part of jruby-openssl gem for a while). thus if you run into OpenSSL related issues your on your own.

Comment: So whats the better solution then